# Delta Method Average Marginal Effects Multinomial Logit

Tags: logistic, standard-error, multinomial-logit, delta-method, marginal-effect

Following the incredible [demonstration in Statalist](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/98078-delta-method-standard-errors-for-average-marginal-effects-using-margins-command?p=100794#post100794) by Jeff Pitblado on how to calculate - using the Delta Method - the Standard Errors for Average Marginal Effects of a Logit Model.

**Q:** What would be the formula to calculate the SEs for the AMEs of a multinomial logit using the Delta Method?

In particular, for the marginal effect (or better, the average partial effects) of a $k$ predictor, taking the derivative w.r.t. to $x_{ik}$ of

$$
Pr\{Y_i=j\} = P_{ij}=\frac{e^{x_i'\beta_j}}{\sum_r e^{x_i'\beta_r}}
$$

will give us

$$
\frac{\partial P_{ij}}{\partial x_{ik}} = P_{ij} \left(\beta_{jk}-\sum_r P_{ir}\beta_{rk}\right)
$$

which is straightforward how to compute.

If I get it right, the formula for the SEs of this AME will be

$$
SE\left(\frac{\partial P_{ij}}{\partial x_{ik}}\right) = J \hat{V} J'
$$

where $\hat{V}$ is the Variance-Covariance matrix of the multinomial logit parameter estimates (and usually returned after estimation in most software like Stata or R) and $J$ is the Jacobian matrix, which is the gap in my calculations.

For the logit model, we can calculate the Jacobian in the following way in Stata:

```r
webuse margex, clear

logit outcome i.treatment distance, nofvlabel
predict p, pr
gen dpdxb   = p*(1-p)
gen dpdx    = dpdxb*_b[distance]
gen d2pdxb2 = p*(1-p)*(1-p) - p*p*(1-p)

matrix vecaccum Jac = d2pdxb2 0b.treatment 1.treatment distance
matrix          Jac = Jac*_b[distance]/e(N)
sum dpdxb
matrix   Jac[1,3] = Jac[1,3] + r(mean)
mat list Jac
```

or in `R' like this:

```r
library(MASS)
data(birthwt)

m        <- glm(low~ smoke + age, binomial(link="logit"), data = birthwt)
p        <- m$fitted.values
dpdxb    <- p*(1-p)
dpdx     <- dpdxb*coef(m)[3]
d2pdxb2  <- p*(1-p)*(1-p) - p*p*(1-p)

Jac      <- t(d2pdxb2)%*%cbind((birthwt$smoke==0)*0, (birthwt$smoke==1)*1, birthwt$age, 1)*coef(m)[3]/length(p)
Jac[1,3] <- Jac[1,3]+mean(dpdxb)
Jac
```

but what would be the way to calculate the Jacobian for the multinomial logit motel?

Comment: Could you specify mathematically "Average Marginal Effects of a Multinomial Logit" in term of regression coefficients of logit model?

Comment: thanks and sorry, you are right I wasn't clear. I edited my question with the formula of what I meant. In short, I want the equivalent of the SE in the `margins, dydx(distance)` that Jeff Pitbaldo calculates manually in his post for logit, but for multinomial logit.

Comment: Sorry I am dodging the question, but perhaps a practical solution would be to consider bootstrapping instead of delta method.

Comment: Thank you @Umka. Yes, I know that's another solution. My aim is to be didactic to myself, rather than estimate the SEs per se. I can always just use the built-in commands, but what I'm after is to understand the formulas.